# How to configure Stackify prefix with tomcat in windows server 2016?

Tags: tomcat, prefix, stackify

1. I have downloaded stackify prefix on windows x64 server.
2. Installed it with Run as Administrator
3. My java agent file location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\StackifyPrefix\java\lib\stackify-java-apm.jar`
4. I navigated to my tomcat installation directory, opened `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat91\bin\catalina.bat` file and inserted `set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -javaagent:"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\StackifyPrefix\\java\\lib\\stackify-java-apm.jar"` just after first set local line.
5. Restarted tomcat server windows service
6. Enabled Prefix .NET Profiler
7. Opened localhost:2012
8. Can not view tomcat requests.
   But I can view my IIS requests. What I am missing here?

**My tomcat version is 9, JDK 1.8, Windows 2016**

Comment: Seems everything is fine. It should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the steps you followed are ok except one thing. When you attach this java agent with tomcat which is installed as windows service, it does not work. 
Follow the steps below:-

1. Download tomcat zip version
2. go to catelina.bat file and include 
   `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251
   set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -javaagent:"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\StackifyPrefix\\java\\lib\\stackify-java-apm.jar"`
3. configure your server.xml and users
4. run startup.bat
5. voila ! it will work now on localhost:2012